# Select MySQL Month() for null column

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Got a question to ask. How do i get to list all of my left table to display the data when i use the left join even when some row got null value in it?

Heres my query:

```
SELECT *, SUM(transactions.debit_credit) current_spending 
FROM (`budget`) LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `budget`.`category`=`categories`.`idcategory` 
LEFT JOIN `user_category` ON `budget`.`category`=`user_category`.`idcategory` 
LEFT JOIN `category_transaction` ON `budget`.`category`=`category_transaction`.`idcategory` 
LEFT JOIN `transactions` ON `category_transaction`.`idtransaction`=`transactions`.`idtransaction` 
WHERE `user_category`.`iduser` = '1' 
AND MONTH(transactions.transaction_date) = '11' 
GROUP BY `budget`.`idbudget`;
```

When I remove `AND MONTH(transactions.transaction_date) = '11'` the query works fine accept it displays all data instead of just 1 month of transaction.

Help?? Please?? Any idea how??

Comment: note that transaction.transaction_date is in the TIMESTAMP datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` clause turns your `left join` into an `inner join` because you filter the data on a condition of a joined table.

Instead put that condition in the `on` clause of your join

```
SELECT *, SUM(transactions.debit_credit) current_spending 
FROM (`budget`) 
LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `budget`.`category`=`categories`.`idcategory` 
LEFT JOIN `user_category` ON `budget`.`category`=`user_category`.`idcategory` 
                         AND `user_category`.`iduser` = '1' 
LEFT JOIN `category_transaction` ON `budget`.`category`=`category_transaction`.`idcategory` 
LEFT JOIN `transactions` ON `category_transaction`.`idtransaction`=`transactions`.`idtransaction` 
                        AND MONTH(transactions.transaction_date) = '11' 
GROUP BY `budget`.`idbudget`;
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I added IFNULL() in the select clause to get my result.